# How to link two tables in django?

Tags: python, django

I use the built-in `User` model in django, but i want use some custom fields, i was create new model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

this is my custom model.
But when i create new user it doesn't display in admin(in profile table), i need to add user from admin panel, after adding it works fine. what i should to do to display Profile info of all users?

p.s. When i was create table profile and was try to select info from joined tabels, sql query  wasn't return anything, but after adding existed user to Profile table sql query return all what i want

Comment: I hope you will not be mad if this is a stupid question

Comment: We have saying: There are no stupid questions, just stupid answers.

Comment: Back to your question: your proplem is, that when you create a `User` no related `Profile` is created as well?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new `Profile` object when a new user is created, you can use a `pre_save receiver`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(
            user=instance
        )
```

The `created` parameter is to check if the object has been created ( `created=True` ) or updated ( `created=False` )

Comment: Thanks a lot to you too!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what you want... If you want to manage profile in admin app you have to register it.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Profile

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Edit: you can use a signal to automatically create a profile when creating a user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from myproject.myapp.models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance **kwargs):
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Note that sometime using signals may be hard to maintain. You can also use AbstractBaseUser. This is a classical issue, which is widely covered in a lot of posts.
One I particularly like: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: nope. I was registered profile table in admin. But it empty, users appear in only after adding it in admin panel. But in build-in django user model user exist.
I mean : i register new user and it display in build-in User model. I want  link two tables "User" and "Profile", but when it done in "Profile" nothing to display. If i add new already created user to "Profile" it start to display, but how to do it automatically. If in build-in "User" we will see new user it should display in "Profile"

Comment: So you want to automatically create a profile when you create a user?

Comment: You should use `get_or_create()` in order to prevent overwriting an already existing profile when the user is saved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can u little help again? After adding your methods got an error: type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'object'. It error exist when i want create new user or login to admin